# Finding the solution to a trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

i'm really struggling to find a useful way to manipulate this trig equation. I probably am overlooking something simple, but i've been working on it for ~1hr to no avail.

Please could you point me in the right direction? Getting started is the hardest part I find.

$$\tan x + 3\cot x = 5\sec x$$

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Multiplying either sides by $\displaystyle\sin x\cos x$ we have $$\sin^2x+3\cos^2x=5\sin x$$

Now use $\displaystyle\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$ and $-1\le \sin x\le1$

Comment: @Jacobadtr, my pleasure. Hope I could make the idea clear

Comment: Absolutely, it all fell into place neatly :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use identities to convert all functions into their $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ equivalents and solve. (sec *x* = 1/cos *x*, tan *x*=sin *x*/cos *x*, cot *x*= cos *x*/sin *x*)

Comment: Hi, welcome to math stack exchange! This is a good hint but here are a couple suggestions that could make your answer even better. First, it's standard formatting on this site to start hints with "HINT:". Also, you might want to consider reminding the OP of the sort of identities that are of use here. (for instance, $\tan(x)= \sin(x)/\cos(x)$)

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan x + 3\cot x = 5\sec x$$
$$\sin x/\cos x + 3\cos x/\sin x = 5/\sin x$$
$$\sin ^2x+3\cos^2x=5\cos x$$
$$1-\cos^2x+3\cos^2x-5\cos x=0$$
$$2\cos^2x-5\cos x+1=0$$
$-1\leq\cos x=t\leq1$
$$2t^2-5t+1=0$$
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{17}}{4}$$
$$x=\arccos t_2=\arccos \frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{4}$$ is the solution because
$$t_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{4}\notin[-1,1]$$